# How to set relative layout size increesing as texview size increese

Tags: android, textview

I am new to android and I am developing an application related to online chat. In a chat screen, I am trying to set chat box size to text view  size.

How can I increase and decrease chat box size as text view size increases and decreases?

Comment: use 9patch image it will do it automatically.

Comment: Used draw9 patch as layout background,but the problem after using 9 patch is I can't add anything inside that layout.When I insert something like image and textview it goes outside of that layout.

Comment: can you show how you tried. share your 9patch image.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Relative Layout` height as `wrap_content` and as well as `textview` height.

`WRAP_CONTENT`, which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content .

Comment: I know about wrap content.But I can't use that for this situation as i need some fixed initial size

Answer (score 1):

see this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:weightSum="1.0"
android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/lefttext" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:maxWidth="250dip"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/righttext" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:maxWidth="250dip"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code inside the getView method of my custom array adapter:

```
View view = convertView;
if(view == null){
     view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}

Resources res = getContext().getResources();
Drawable bubblesChat = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bubbles_chat);
Drawable bubblesResponse = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bubbles_response);
TextView left = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lefttext);
TextView right = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.righttext);

String txt = super.getItem(position);
if(txt.startsWith("s:")) {
    left.setText(getItem(position));
    left.setBackgroundDrawable(bubblesChat);
    right.setText("");
    right.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
} else {
    right.setText(getItem(position));
    right.setBackgroundDrawable(bubblesResponse);
    left.setText("");
    left.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
}
return view;
```

[Alternate chat bubble widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101835/alternate-chat-bubble-widths)
and  http://warting.se/2012/06/04/chat-bubbles-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can take a layout preferably a `RelativeLayout` and whenever your `TextView` size increases or decreases refresh your chatview by setting new `LayoutParams` dynamically.